# ebpf script hangs at hash map clear

Tags: python, ebpf

I'm trying to collect information about network of server. I write a bcc script, it works fine on most servers, but hangs at BPF_HASH clear function when it runs on a machine with heavy network traffic(receive and transmit are both about 500MB/s).

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Mon May 29 09:56:21 2023
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "network.py", line 216, in <module>
    run(args)
  File "network.py", line 96, in run
    ipv4_recv.clear()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc/table.py", line 412, in clear
    self.__delitem__(k)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc/table.py", line 381, in __delitem__
    res = lib.bpf_delete_elem(self.map_fd, ct.byref(key))
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My full script is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
from socket import inet_ntop, AF_INET, AF_INET6
from struct import pack
from time import sleep, localtime, asctime, time
from bcc import BPF
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Summarize TCP send/recv throughput by host",
                                 formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, )
parser.add_argument("-i", "--interval", type=float, default=1)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--count", type=int, default=99999999, help="count of outputs")
args = parser.parse_args()

print_interval = args.interval + 0.0
if print_interval <= 0:
    print("print interval must stricly positive")
    exit()

bpf_text = """
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <bcc/proto.h>

struct ipv4_data_t {
    u32 pid;
    u32 saddr;
    u32 daddr;
    u16 sport;
    u16 dport;
    char task[TASK_COMM_LEN];
};
BPF_HASH(ipv4_send, struct ipv4_data_t);
BPF_HASH(ipv4_recv, struct ipv4_data_t);

struct ipv6_data_t {
    u32 pid;
    unsigned __int128 saddr;
    unsigned __int128 daddr;
    u16 sport;
    u16 dport;
    u64 __pad__;
    char task[TASK_COMM_LEN];
};


BPF_HASH(ipv6_send, struct ipv6_data_t);
BPF_HASH(ipv6_recv, struct ipv6_data_t);
BPF_HASH(sock_store, u32, struct sock *);

static int tcp_sendstat(int size) {
    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;

    struct sock **skpp;
    skpp = sock_store.lookup(&pid);
    if (skpp == 0) {
        return 0; //miss the entry
    }

    struct sock *skp = *skpp;
    u16 family, dport;
    bpf_probe_read_kernel(&family, sizeof(family), &skp->__sk_common.skc_family);
    bpf_probe_read_kernel(&dport, sizeof(dport), &skp->__sk_common.skc_dport);

    if (family == AF_INET) {
        struct ipv4_data_t data4 = {.pid = pid};
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data4.saddr, sizeof(data4.saddr), &skp->__sk_common.skc_rcv_saddr);
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data4.daddr, sizeof(data4.daddr), &skp->__sk_common.skc_daddr);
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data4.sport, sizeof(data4.sport), &skp->__sk_common.skc_num);
        data4.dport = ntohs(dport);
        bpf_get_current_comm(&data4.task, sizeof(data4.task));
        ipv4_send.increment(data4, size);

    } else if (family == AF_INET6) {
        struct ipv6_data_t data6 = {.pid = pid};
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data6.saddr, sizeof(data6.saddr), &skp->__sk_common.skc_v6_rcv_saddr.in6_u.u6_addr32);
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data6.daddr, sizeof(data6.daddr), &skp->__sk_common.skc_v6_daddr.in6_u.u6_addr32);
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data6.sport, sizeof(data6.sport), &skp->__sk_common.skc_num);
        data6.dport = ntohs(dport);
        bpf_get_current_comm(&data6.task, sizeof(data6.task));
        ipv6_send.increment(data6, size);
    }
    sock_store.delete(&pid);

    return 0;
}

int kretprobe__tcp_sendmsg(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    int size = PT_REGS_RC(ctx);
    if (size > 0)
        return tcp_sendstat(size);
    else
        return 0;
}

int kretprobe__tcp_sendpage(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    int size = PT_REGS_RC(ctx);
    if (size > 0)
        return tcp_sendstat(size);
    else
        return 0;
}

static int tcp_send_entry(struct sock *sk) {
    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    u16 family = sk->__sk_common.skc_family;
    sock_store.update(&pid, &sk);
    return 0;
}

int kprobe__tcp_sendmsg(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sock *sk, struct msghdr *msg, size_t size) {
    return tcp_send_entry(sk);
}

int kprobe__tcp_sendpage(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sock *sk, struct page *page, int offset, size_t size) {
    return tcp_send_entry(sk);
}

int kprobe__tcp_cleanup_rbuf(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sock *sk, int copied) {
    u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;

    u16 family = sk->__sk_common.skc_family;
    u16 sport = sk->__sk_common.skc_num;
    u16 dport = sk->__sk_common.skc_dport;
    dport = ntohs(dport);

    if (copied <= 0)
        return 0;

    if (family == AF_INET) {
        struct ipv4_data_t data4 = {.pid = pid};
        data4.saddr = sk->__sk_common.skc_rcv_saddr;
        data4.daddr = sk->__sk_common.skc_daddr;
        data4.sport = sport;
        data4.dport = dport;
        bpf_get_current_comm(&data4.task, sizeof(data4.task));
        ipv4_recv.increment(data4, copied);

    } else if (family == AF_INET6) {
        struct ipv6_data_t data6 = {.pid = pid};
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data6.saddr, sizeof(data6.saddr),
            &sk->__sk_common.skc_v6_rcv_saddr.in6_u.u6_addr32);
        bpf_probe_read_kernel(&data6.daddr, sizeof(data6.daddr),
            &sk->__sk_common.skc_v6_daddr.in6_u.u6_addr32);
        data6.sport = sport;
        data6.dport = dport;
        bpf_get_current_comm(&data6.task, sizeof(data6.task));
        ipv6_recv.increment(data6, copied);
    }

    return 0;
}
"""

TCPSessionKey = namedtuple('TCPSession', ['pid', 'task', 'saddr', 'sport', 'daddr', 'dport'])


def get_ipv4_session_key(k):
    return TCPSessionKey(pid=k.pid, task=k.task, saddr=inet_ntop(AF_INET, pack("I", k.saddr)),
                         sport=k.sport, daddr=inet_ntop(AF_INET, pack("I", k.daddr)), dport=k.dport)


def get_ipv6_session_key(k):
    return TCPSessionKey(pid=k.pid, task=k.task, saddr=inet_ntop(AF_INET6, k.saddr),
                         sport=k.sport, daddr=inet_ntop(AF_INET6, k.daddr), dport=k.dport)



count = 0

b = BPF(text=bpf_text)

ipv4_send = b["ipv4_send"]
ipv4_recv = b["ipv4_recv"]
ipv6_send = b["ipv6_send"]
ipv6_recv = b["ipv6_recv"]
while 1:

    count += 1

    try:
        sleep(args.interval)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()

    # -------- IPv4: build dict of all seen keys --------
    ipv4_throughput = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
    for k, v in ipv4_send.items():
        key = get_ipv4_session_key(k)
        ipv4_throughput[key][0] = v.value
    ipv4_send.clear()

    for k, v in ipv4_recv.items():
        key = get_ipv4_session_key(k)
        ipv4_throughput[key][1] = v.value
    # hangs at here
    ipv4_recv.clear()

    # -------- IPv4: output --------
    if ipv4_throughput:
        for k, (send_bytes, recv_bytes) in ipv4_throughput.items():
            print("%-7d %-15s %-22s %-22s %6d %6d" % ( 
                    k.pid, k.task.decode(),
                    "%s:%d" % (k.saddr, k.sport), "%s:%d" % (k.daddr, k.dport),
                    int(recv_bytes/1024), int(send_bytes/1024)))

    # -------- IPv6: build dict of all seen keys --------
    ipv6_throughput = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
    for k, v in ipv6_send.items():
        key = get_ipv6_session_key(k)
        ipv6_throughput[key][0] = v.value
    ipv6_send.clear()

    for k, v in ipv6_recv.items():
        key = get_ipv6_session_key(k)
        ipv6_throughput[key][1] = v.value
    ipv6_recv.clear()

    # -------- IPv6: output --------
    if ipv6_throughput:
        print("\n%-7s %-15s %-42s %-42s %6s %6s" %
                  ("PID", "TASK", "SADDR6:SPORT", "DADDR6:DPORT", "RX_KB", "TX_KB"))

        print("%-7d %-15s %-22s %-22s %6d %6d" % ( 
                    k.pid, k.task.decode(),
                    "%s:%d" % (k.saddr, k.sport), "%s:%d" % (k.daddr, k.dport),
                    int(recv_bytes/1024), int(send_bytes/1024)))
```

Is it because there are too many items in the map, and there are always new items, so it keeps looping？
I learned that the function items_lookup_and_delete_batch may be able to solve this problem, but it requires kernel version 5.6, and mine is 4.19. Is it possible to solve this problem without upgrading the kernel?

Comment: If you're looking to flush the whole map, why don't you create a new instance of the map and reload the BPF program to use the new instance?